# How to pass values to nested ForEach?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use a variable created in an outer ForEach loop inside an inner ForEach loop.  The value does not pass thru as I expect and is always null.

Notice The value for $server is always null can you tell me why and how to fix?

```
$Srvrs = "SVR1";
$Srvrs | ForEach-Object {


    $server = $_;
    Write-Host "Server value in outer Foreach:" $server;

    $sourceFilesLoc = "D:\Test\SetupSoftwareAndFiles"
    $sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $sourceFilesLoc;

    $sourceFiles | ForEach-Object  {
        Start-Job -InputObject $server -ScriptBlock     {
            Write-Host "Server value in inner Foreach:" $server;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pass in the parameters via the `-ArgumentList` parameter e.g.:

```
Start-Job -InputObject $server -ScriptBlock {param($svr)
    Write-Host "Server value in inner Foreach:" $svr;
} -ArgumentList $server
```

Here's a simple example of using `-ArgumentList`:

```
PS> $server = 'acme'
PS> $job = Start-Job {param($svr) "server is $svr"} -ArgumentList $server
PS> Receive-Job $job
server is acme
```

Comment: Same result with .GetNewClosure()

Comment: The syntax you provided does not work so I altered it to:
Start-Job -InputObject $server -ArgumentList $server -ScriptBlock  {param($svr)
   Write-Host "Server value in inner Foreach:" $server;
   }
  } 

The result is still null for inner value.

Comment: See the example above `$server = 'acme'` - works just fine.  BTW you don't need to use `-InputObject` since that variable is visible to the rest of the script within the block its defined in.

Comment: To get variables into a Start-Job you have to pass them in the -ArgumentList

Comment: @Chili, you need to use the name of the parameter, not $Server.

Answer (score 2):

the issue isn't accessing the variable in nested foreaches.. if you did a write-host of the variable inside the inner foreach it would be fine. Its a matter of passing the variable to the job. Jobs are different processes that run in the background.